# Jquery Slider like Power Point Slides

Tags: jquery

I am working on a project,in which I have to implement Flash Cards, Users can add Images or text and then play them online like power point presentation For eg like [This](http://quizlet.com/1890295/unit-15-part-2-flash-cards/)

I have used Jquery Cycle plugin,but its not playing files like this link, Can any one suggest how can I achieve this functionality?Below is my code

```
<span id="prev">Prev</span></a> <a href="javascript:void(0);"><span id="next">Next</span></a>
<div class="pics" id="slideshow">

                    @foreach (var item in Model.CardContent)
                    {
                        if (item.ImagePath != null)
                        {
                        <img src="../../FlashCardsImages/@item.ImagePath" width="200" height="200" />
                        }
                        <p>@item.Answer</p>
                    }            
            </div>


  $('#slideshowsssss').cycle({ fx: 'scrollHorz', timeout: 0, prev: '#prev', next: '#next' });
```

Regards

Comment: Can we see some code?

Comment: I've used JCarousel in the past: https://github.com/jsor/jcarousel and some demos here http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/

Comment: I have used JCarousel but I dont think that this is JCarousel

Comment: I have both text and Images, and I can have only Text or only Images in one slide